# CONCAT_GROUP() the way around

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query which works perfectly but the results out of `CONCAT_GROUP()` are the way around than I want.

Query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(parent.place_name) AS place_name
    FROM address AS node,
        address AS parent
    WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
    GROUP BY node.id
    ORDER BY node.lft"
```

`address` table:

```
------------------------------------
id  |   place_name   |  lft | rgt
~-----------------------------------
1   |   A            | 1    | 4
~-----------------------------------
2   |   B            | 2    | 3
~-----------------------------------
```

The result of `place_name` will be:

`A`

`A, B`

But I need it to be:

`A`

`B, A`

I tried to play with `ORDER` but I failed to get it right. Can you help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the 3rd example in [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT parent.place_name ORDER BY parent.lft DESC SEPARATOR ',') AS place_name
    FROM address AS node,
        address AS parent
    WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
    GROUP BY node.id
```